# Why my color picker is not working it is not allowing me to pick color and there is no error too?

Tags: html, jquery, css, color-picker

```
    @extends('layouts.admin')
@section('title_page','Car Exterior Color')
@section('content')
<div class="card">

    <div class="card-body">
        @if (session('status'))
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            {{ session('status') }}
        </div>
        @endif
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
            <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createEditModal" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add New </button>
        </div>
        &nbsp;
        <table class="table table-bordered data-table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Color Title(EN)</th>
                    <th scope="col"> Color Title(AR)</th>
                    <th scope="col">Color Code</th>
                    <th scope="col">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

@include('cars.exterior_color.create_edit_modal')

@endsection

@section('additional_css')
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css">
@endsection

@section('additional_js')
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/3.2.0/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        App.Cars.ExteriorColors = {
            loadEditData(e) {
                var $url = $(e).attr('href');
                $.get($url, function($response) {
                    $('#createEditForm').trigger('reset');
                    $('#createEditModal').modal('show');
                    $('#exterior_color').val($response.resp.exterior_color);
                    $('#exterior_color_ar').val($response.resp.exterior_color_ar);
                    $('#color_code').val($response.resp.color_code);
                    $('#method').val("PUT");
                    $('#url').val($response.route);
                    $(".close").on("click", function() {
                        $("#createEditModal").modal('hide');
                    });
                    $("#close-btn").on("click", function() {
                        $("#createEditModal").modal('hide');
                    });
                })
            },

        }

        App.Cars.saveData('{{ route("cars.exteriorcolors.store")}}')
        App.Cars.resetData();
        var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: "{{ route('cars.exteriorcolors.listing') }}",
                method: 'POST'
            },
            columns: [{
                    data: 'uid',
                    name: 'uid'
                },
                {
                    data: 'name',
                    name: 'name'
                },
                {
                    data: 'name_ar',
                    name: 'name_ar'
                },
                {
                    data: 'code',
                    name: 'code'
                },
                {
                    data: 'action',
                    name: 'action',
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false
                },
            ]
        });

    });
    $("#modulesForm").validate();
    var color = $("#color_code").val();
    $("#component-colorpicker").colorpicker({
        format: "hex",
        color: color,

    });
</script>
@endsection
```

why i am unable to pick the color from color picker i have done all things right @include('cars.exterior_color.create_edit_modal')this have the modal which have all id's and when i am doing it in separate page the some code worked but in this page not working i have included the whole page because maybe there are some links which are conflicting but i am not getting where i am going wrong and what to do

Comment: Where exactly is your color picker element? Couldn't find any element with id `component-colorpicker` in that code

Comment: It is in other file in modal which is included here